# Android JSoup with AsyncTask - can't see the content

Tags: android

I use this code inorder to get the content of some website.
the textview stay empty. What I am doing wrong?
I added the jar into librires and also add internet permission to manifest.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyTask mt;
  TextView tvInfo;
  String URL="http://www.example.com/";
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
    mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute(URL);
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      Document doc;
      String title=null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      tvInfo.setText("Please wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      try {
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      // doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
      // String title = doc.title();

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
       Element content = doc.select("a").first();
       title = content.text();

       Log.d("AsyncTask doInBackground","URL: " + params[0]);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return title;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.setText(title);
    }
  }
}
```

I also not understand excaly when each method here is called
THANKS A LOT!

EDIT - the code after what was suggested in answer. Still not working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    MyTask mt;
    TextView tvInfo;
    String URL="http://www.example.com/";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tvInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String title = "hh";
            try{
                Document doc =   Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
                 title = doc.title();
                System.out.println("title : " + title);

                // get all links
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                for (Element link : links) {

                    // get the value from href attribute
                    System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                    System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;

        }      

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tvInfo.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            tvInfo.setText("Please wait");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute(URL);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask executes everything in `doInBackground()` inside of another thread, which does not have access to the GUI where your views are.

`preExecute()` and `postExecute()` offer you access to GUI before and after the heavy lifting occurs in this new thread, you can even pass the result of the long operation to `postExecute()` to then show any results of processing.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      try{
            Document doc =   Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);

            // get all links
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {

            // get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
      } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            tvInfo.setText("Please wait");
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you exaplantion.

Comment: @user1932595 No instead of you `myTask` class. Leave the MainActivity as it is and If you find my answer useful, please vote it up and accept it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: @user1932595 Note: you code was wrong. I have edit your question to perform the onClickListner well. Use the new code

Comment: It should print in the consul the output

Comment: @user1932595 add the new line I have put before "Please wait" and try again...super.onPreExecute();

Comment: still the same problem